# Vuejs: how to cycle through highlighted search terms using prev / next

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to let the user cycle through the highlighted occurrences of a found search string, using 'next / previous' arrows, similar to what's shown here from Google Docs:

[image]

I know how to highlight all occurrences using a filter and a regexp :

```html
<p v-html="$options.filters.highlightSearchResults(theText,  searchTerms)"></p>
```

and:

```js
filters: {
  highlightSearchResults(theText, searchTerms) {
    const re = new RegExp(searchTerms, "gi")
    return theText.replace(re, (match) => `<span style="background-color:#ffff00">${match}</span>`
  }
```

but I'm scratching my head on how go about cycling through the found instances. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `currentIndex` that refers to the index of the currently highlighted occurrence (and is updated by the Next/Prev buttons).

```js
export default {
  data() {
    currentIndex: 0,
  }
}
```

Also, keep an iterator index in your string replacer that only returns a highlighting `<span>` if the index matches the `currentIndex`:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    highlightSearchResults(theText, searchTerms) {
      const re = new RegExp(searchTerms, 'gi')
      let i = 0
      return theText.replace(re, (match) =>
        (i++ == this.currentIndex)
                             ? `<span style="background-color:#ffff00">${match}</span>`
                             : match
      )
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwaONxP)

Also consider replacing `highlightSearchResults` from the template with a computed prop for improved rendering performance, as the value's [cache](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) would be used on the next render:

```html
<template>
  <p v-html="highlightedText"></p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    highlightedText() {
      return this.highlightSearchResults(this.theText, this.searchTerms)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/oNxROOZ)